# create login form using soap webservice in android

Tags: java, android, mysql, web-services, soap

Hi i have to develop one login form in android calling soap webservice.

This is my webservice code:

```
public class XcartLogin {
public String authentication(String userName,String password){

String retrievedUserName = "";
String retrievedPassword = "";
String status = "";
try{

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart432-pro","root","");
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM xcart_customers WHERE login = '"+userName+"'");
ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

while(result.next()){
retrievedUserName = result.getString("login");
retrievedPassword = result.getString("password");
}

if(retrievedUserName.equals(userName)&&retrievedPassword.equals(password)&&!(retrievedUserName.equals("") && retrievedPassword.equals(""))){
status = "Success";

}

else {
status = "Login fail!!!";
}

}

 catch(Exception e){
 e.printStackTrace();
}
return status;

}

}
```

it is successfully worked for me.if i have to run the android app and entered correct login detail means its displayed success message and entered wrong information means displayed login fail message.

But i wish to need the o/p is,

if login is successful means the success message shouldn't display.have to enter wrong information means should display login fail message.

How can i develop the webservice code.please help me.